# How can I filter based on count within a dimension in a stacked bar chart?

Tags: looker-studio

### Background

I have a Google Data Studio report showing Google Forms survey results based on different demographics. I need to protect the anonymity of people that responded to the form so I do not want to show the results if fewer than 5 people responded from either an individual demographic category or from a combination of categories.

In my Google Data Studio report I have a stacked bar chart showing the breakdown of how people responded to the question. The chart has a dimension that can be selected from a data control and then it is possible to drill down into the data. I then have 9 separate dropdown list data controls to allow the user to filter by different demographics.

Stacked bar chart from Google Data Studio:

[image: Stacked bar chart from data studio]

| Gender | Hair colour | Eye colour | Question response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Man | Blond | Blue |  |
| Man | Brown | Blue | Probably |
| Man | Black | Brown | Not at all |
| Man | Blond | Blue | Probably |
| Man | Brown | Green | Definitely |
| Man | Black | Brown | Neutral |
| Man | Blond | Blue | Definitely |
| Man | Brown | Brown | Probably |

### Question

How do I apply a filter to the dimension so the dimension does not show if there were fewer than 5 responses for that dimension? I still want it to show the data for the dimension if there were >5 responses for the individual segments of the stacked bar chart

### Attempt

I am able to assign null values if there were fewer than 5 respondents from an individual demographic in my data prep. I am also able to ensure the dropdown list data controls do not show categories where there were fewer than 5 responses by applying a filter to each data control. However if I apply the same filter to the chart, it filters out any segment of the stacked bar chart where there were fewer than 5 responses rather than if there were 5 responses to the whole dimension/demographic

Filter configuration:

[image: Filter configuration]

Resulting bar chart with no data:

[image: Resulting bar chart with no data]

### Expected output

When `Hair colour` is selected as 'Blond' only in the data control, the bar chart should show a stacked bar for 'Man' but no stacked bar for 'Woman' as there are fewer than 5 responses for 'Woman'

### Sample

- Data Set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vmbtHnBKleTJORqyc2vhBJ8GlZMXcgoDHZ4cCVqyabM/edit#gid=0))
- [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4476440c-f322-4087-8d76-013a0d59835c) report

If I select `Hair colour` = blond from the data control, there are 7 responses from men and 2 from women. I want the responses from men to display but not for women as there were only 2 women with blond hair in our sample which is less than 5. If I apply a filter exclude record count < 5, then it removes men from the chart as well as women because there were fewer than 5 responses for each survey option ('Definitely', 'Probably' etc.).

Comment: @Nimantha I think your answer here almost gets me there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998421/how-can-i-re-categorize-any-counts-n-in-google-data-studio. But the challenge is because this is a stacked bar chart, it is still removing the answer options which received fewer than 5 responses (in the updated sample data studio report, post-blend chart - neutral and not at all are removed because there were fewer than 5 responses)

Comment: Been meaning to have a look at this.... If it's still unresolved, will take a look and get back by the end of the month (hopefully will get a chance during the weekend)

Comment: Okay thank you!! I keep coming back to it but then get stuck! I've managed to replicate what you were able to do on that other question now, so I can show as REDACTED when there are fewer than 5 responses. I'm now just trying to work out how to filter out REDACTED so it doesn't display on the chart. I'll let you know if I come up with anything before the weekend :)

Comment: @Nimantha if you have a moment to look over the weekend, that would still be very helpful! I've tried implementing in my environment which has a drill-down, a fixed size list and quite a few null values in addition and it's not quite working. I've put together a version of the report with a sample here: [link]https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/3e1400b6-8371-49ea-b667-29a8e7984348/page/z1NwC/edit. The issue is when selecting Race/ethnicity as the Characteristic, I would expect Minoritised ethnic (non-dominant) to show on the top chart as there are 15 responses but it doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using a version of Nimantha's answer to this question: [How can I re-categorize any counts < n in Google Data Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998421/how-can-i-re-categorize-any-counts-n-in-google-data-studio). I basically wanted to achieve the same thing but on a stacked bar chart and I wanted to remove the redacted responses completely from the chart.

As in Nimantha's answer to the question above, I created a calculated field containing COUNT(Gender) in my main data source. The additional step was I then created a simple bar chart with Gender as the dimension and Count Gender in the metric field. The key was to apply a filter to this chart which excludes that count gender calculated field if the count is less than x (in my case 5).

I then blended that chart with my original chart (both using the same data source) with a left join on Gender. I then re-created the stacked bar chart using the same fields (gender in dimension, question response in breakdown dimension and record count as the metric. This chart inherits the filter from the helper chart to remove the dimension if gender count is less than 5.

I've updated my original sample to show this in action here: https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4476440c-f322-4087-8d76-013a0d59835c

[Click here to view screenshot of working version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02iDs.png)