# How can I re-categorize any counts < n in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm creating a dashboard that shows some demographic information for a population. However, in cases where less than 25 individuals show a certain demographic trait, I need to be able to re-categorize that trait as "REDACTED" to protect privacy.

A pseudo-code version might be:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN COUNT(gender) < 25 THEN "REDACTED"
  ELSE gender
END
```

Unfortunately, this mixes aggregation and non-aggregation and isn't workable in a calculated field.

I'm hoping for some suggestions on how to solve preferably without aggregating first in the data source --I'd like to be for my data and blends to exist at the individual grain with aggregation happening within Google Data Studio.

[Publicly-Editable Example Google Data Studio report](https://datastudio.google.com/s/ihgiodk02HI)

Data source (INPUT) is the source, also available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jsZPx5DOqi7QaHNVl1Wnnp12BGHHrv-F/view?usp=sharing).

Expected output:

| gender | count |
| --- | --- |
| female | 222 |
| male | 223 |
| REDACTED | 55 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 0) Summary

The below looks at:

1. ***Issue***: "*calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values)*"
2. ***Suggestion***: [Reaggregating](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9429470) data using a [blend](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420)

## 1) Issue

A system error is displayed:

> Sorry, calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values). Please check the aggregation types of the fields used in this formula. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7569962#troubleshoot-calculated-fields).

when using the [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) in the question:

```
CASE
  WHEN COUNT(gender) < 25 THEN "REDACTED"
  ELSE gender
END
```

This ("*aggregated values*") refers to the 2nd line in the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724), specifically the aggregated field:

[`COUNT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583207)`(gender)`

## 2) Suggestion

One way is to use [reaggregation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9429470) with a [blend](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420), by performing a self blend (where the data source of both tables are the same) and creating a dedicated `COUNT(gender)` field (titled `gender_count` below):

### 2.1) Blend Fields

| Table 1 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
| ***Dimension #1***: `gender` | ***Dimension #1***: `gender` |
| ***Dimension #2***: `person_id` |  |
| ***Dimension #3***: `dept` |  |
| ***Metric***: `Record Count` | ***Metric***: `gender` ***Aggregation***: [`COUNT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583207) ***Rename***: `gender_count` |
| [image: table_1] | [image: table_2] |

### 2.2) Join Configuration

| Join Description | Table 1 Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
| **Join Operator** | Left Outer |
| **Join Condition** | `gender` `gender` |
| **Image** | [image: join] |

In summary, the result of the blend will look like:

[image: blend_summary]

### 2.3) Pie Chart

- ***Dimension***:

  ```sql
  CASE
    WHEN gender_count < 25 THEN "REDACTED"
    ELSE gender
  END
  ```
- ***Metric***: `Record Count`

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9744fe28-d5ce-4520-bbee-4fcb49f7ef13) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/150p-q1H0MCWjuP8irfld0OyyosxA9OrDvG1o4GEFAuI/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Data Studio doesn't let you use an aggregate function ([`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212), [`AVG`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583518), [`COUNT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583207)) in a [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement and return a dimension. However there is a workaround for this. First create a field like this:

**field1**

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN COUNT(gender) < 25 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

then create a second one like this

**field2**

```sql
CASE
  WHEN field1 = 1 THEN "REDACTED"
  ELSE gender
END
```

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't work. I can create field1 just fine but DS sees it as an aggregated field and thus field2 gets the familiar "
Sorry, calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values). Please check the aggregation types of the fields used in this formula."